# PHPExcel won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpexcel

I'm trying to print my SQL query that I have generated in PHP to an Excel file using PHPExcel. I'm not sure where I've made a mistake, but every time I run my code, I get a blank page.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
mysql_connect("$host", $user, $password) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on     $myServer");
mysql_select_db("$database") or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
}
require_once("includes/session.php"); 
require_once("includes/connection.php"); 
require_once("includes/functions.php");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '
');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$filter = $_SESSION['registry'];
$query = "SELECT sales.invoiceNo, invoiceDate, dueDate, customerID, customerName, dateTrans, postDate, description, grossSale, vat, netSale, quantity, branch, despatchNote  FROM sales2012 sales WHERE sales.invoiceNo IN (SELECT invoiceNo FROM sales2012 GROUP BY invoiceNo HAVING COUNT(invoiceNo)>1)";
$result_set = mysql_query($query);
        confirm_query($result_set);

// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Invoice No')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'Invoice Date')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Due Date')
        ->setCellValue('D1', 'Customer ID')
        ->setCellValue('E1', 'Customer Name')
        ->setCellValue('F1', 'Transaction Date')
        ->setCellValue('G1', 'Post Date')
        ->setCellValue('H1', 'Description')
        ->setCellValue('I1', 'Gross Sale')
        ->setCellValue('J1', 'VAT')
        ->setCellValue('K1', 'Net Sale')
        ->setCellValue('L1', 'Quantity')
        ->setCellValue('M1', 'Branch')
        ->setCellValue('N1', 'Despatch Note');


        $row = 2;
       while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A' . $row, $data['invoiceNo'])
        ->setCellValue('B'. $row, $data['invoiceDate'])
        ->setCellValue('C'. $row, $data['dueDate'])
        ->setCellValue('D'. $row, $data['customerID'])
        ->setCellValue('E'. $row, $data['customerName'])
        ->setCellValue('F'. $row, $data['dateTrans'])
        ->setCellValue('G'. $row, $data['postDate'])
        ->setCellValue('H'. $row, $data['description'])
        ->setCellValue('I'. $row, $data['grossSale'])
        ->setCellValue('J'. $row, $data['vat'])
        ->setCellValue('K'. $row, $data['netSale'])
        ->setCellValue('L'. $row, $data['quantity'])
        ->setCellValue('M'. $row, $data['branch'])
        ->setCellValue('N'. $row, $data['descriptionNote']);
        $row++;
       }

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('__FILE__,'/desktop/filename.xls',__FILE__));

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_STRICT | E_ALL);` to the top of your PHP to see any errors there might be. Ignore me... Just seen you already have that.

Comment: I think a blank page is correct here. There is nothing outputting to the screen in that file. It is saving to a .xls file on the desktop

Comment: When I check the desktop I have no .xls file

Answer (score 0):

maybe bucause you have the include : librarie excel2007

> require_once("Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php");

and when you save the document in excel2007 the extention is .xlsx

> $objWriter->save(str_replace('**FILE**,'/desktop/filename.xls',**FILE**));

this can be a option

> $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
>
> $objWriter->save('php://output')

Comment: @goroved - when something "doesn't work", it's always helpful to say what you mean by "doesn't work". Does it display any error messages? does it write anything to PHP or webserver logs? does it electrocute you? does it write a file containing invalid data?

Answer (score 0):

```
$objWriter->save(
    str_replace('__FILE__,'/desktop/filename.xls',__FILE__)
);
```

Your str_replace() isn't valid syntax for PHP, I'm surprised this error isn't being logged somewhere... mismatched quotes, as any decent syntax highlighting editor would have told you

And the silly thing is, you don't even need the str_replace. The PHPExcel Writer save() method expects a string value as a filename, it doesn't care how that string is generated, so just pass it a string

```
$objWriter->save('/desktop/filename.xls');
```